# Date.today updation issue in rails and postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have rake task which is having following line:

```
p "----------#{Date.today}"
p "--add_date---- #{add_date}"

Finder.find_by_app_id(lr.app_id).update_attributes(:last_delivery_at => Date.today,:next_run_date => add_date)
```

which gives in console

> "----------2016-05-26"
>
> "--add_date---- 2016-05-27 00:00:00 +0530"

but in Postgresql database :
`last_delivery_at : 2016-05-25`
`next_run_date : 2016-05-26` (it supposed to be `2016-05-27` as per my logic)

how this date is getting -1 day when it is updating in database?

Comment: I think you should change your `date` column type to a `datetime` column to get a clear idea why you are not getting expected value.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to get date

```
Date.today.strftime
```

Answer (score 0):

To save date in local timezone to database check your config/application.rb

`config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`